# Using loops to run multiple functions and save output separately

Tags: r

Apologies for the terrible description. I'm sure this is a very simple problem to solve, but I'm very new to loops and haven't been able to figure it out. I also don't know how to provide reproducible spatial data, so....

I have spatial data consisting of a series of points from a tagged animal.  I'm using the package `adehabitat` to create minimum convex polygons containing variable percentages of the points. I'm then saving each polygon as a .shp file named with a unique animal id, the date range, and the percentage, and saving it to different directory depending on what site it comes from. This is an operation I perform a lot, so I'd like to automate it as much as possible.

This is what I'm using now:

```
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(rgdal)

df <- read.csv('data.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

site <- 'SiteName'
date <- '2019-06-22_2019-07-20'
id <- 'HAR04'

# The adehabitat packages requires data to be in a spatial format.
coordinates(df) <- df[, c('lon', 'lat')]
proj4string(df) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# Create the polygons for each percentage point.
# The column specified just refers to the id, which adehabitat requires
mcp_est100 <- mcp(df[, 2], percent = 100)
mcp_est90 <- mcp(df[, 2], percent = 90)
mcp_est50 <- mcp(df[, 2], percent = 50)

# Save the polygons as shapefiles.
writeOGR(obj=mcp_est100,
         dsn=site,
         layer=paste(id, '_', date, '_100', sep=''), 
         driver='ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer=TRUE)

writeOGR(obj=mcp_est90,
         dsn=site,
         layer=paste(id, '_', date, '_90', sep=''), 
         driver='ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer=TRUE)

writeOGR(obj=mcp_est50,
         dsn=site,
         layer=paste(id, '_', date, '_50', sep=''), 
         driver='ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

You can see the code is highly repetitive and requires me to make changes in multiple locations if anything varies (ie, if I want 80% polygons instead of 50%). Is there a way for me to streamline this using `for` loops or some kind of `apply` function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `purrr::walk` in your situation. It's a nice substitute of the `for` loop. You need to define a function and a range of values it needs to be run on:

```
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(rgdal)

df <- read.csv('data.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

site <- 'SiteName'
date <- '2019-06-22_2019-07-20'
id <- 'HAR04'

# The adehabitat packages requires data to be in a spatial format.
coordinates(df) <- df[, c('lon', 'lat')]
proj4string(df) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

purrr::walk(c(100, 90, 50), function(x){
  writeOGR(obj=mcp(df[, 2], percent = x),
           dsn=site,
           layer=paste(id, '_', date, '_', as.character(x), sep=''), 
           driver='ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer=TRUE)
})
```

From the reference:

> walk() returns the input .x (invisibly). This makes it easy to use in
>   pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Slavas approach would be my go to solution as well. However, since OP asked for a for loop, this should mirror your code 1:1 (although not with best performance):

```
for(i in c(100, 90, 50)){
  assign(paste0("mcp_est", i),
         value = mcp(df[, 2], percent = i))

  writeOGR(obj=get(paste0("mcp_est", i)),
           dsn=site,
           layer=paste(id, '_', date, '_', i, sep=''), 
           driver='ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Also works perfectly, but I marked Slavas' answer as the solution for elegance.